# How to select only the 3 most recent files inside a 'foreach'

Tags: powershell

There's probably a very easy solution to this but I have the following part of code inside a function that simply gets a list of files from $src folder and copies them to a $dest folder. However I'd like to make it so it copies only the 3 most recent files (or less if there is less than 3, and skip without error if there are none).

The closest example I found was:

```
foreach ($_ in 1..10){
...
}
```

But I already have an "in" inside my foreach () so I don't know how to make it work and I'm not even sure this is the right solution.

How do I accomplish my goal?

```
       foreach ($File in $Filelist)
        {
            $Filename=$File.Fullname.tolower().replace($Source,'')
            $DestinationFile=($Destination+$Filename)
            Write-Progress -Activity "Copying files from '$source' to '$Destination'" -Status "Copying File $Filename" -PercentComplete (($Position/$total)*100)
            Copy-Item $File.FullName -Destination $DestinationFile -Force
            $Position++
        }
```

Comment: To select the most current, you can sort by date, and use `-First 3` in your `Select-Object`. The selection will have to be made from your `$filelist` unless you'd like to reassign the first 3 to another variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -First 3` to get only the first 3 input items - then we just need to sort on `LastWriteTime`, in descending order:

```
foreach($File in $FileList |Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |Select-Object -First 3){
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Select-Object -First 3 is what I was referring to for other commands but I didn't know I could also use it inside a foreach.

Comment: @yorkman You're most welcome! The syntax is basically `foreach($variable in <pipeline expression>) { ... }` :)